# Data-migration from v2 to v3 QBO

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, data-migration, quickbooks-online

We've done all the code-migration from v2 to v3 REST API of QuickBooks Online. The question is - how about the data from v2?** We have a test account v2 with a lot of test data within. We store all the QbReferenceIDs in our database, **will they stay the same for QBO v3?**

Answer (score 1):

No, the ID will change. See the IdType section at https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#IdType for more details on how it changes.

Comment: I didn't mean the _WAY_ IDs are generated/stored. 

Example: we have 10 invoices saved from our App to the QBO. All of 10 invoices have their IDs in QBO (numeric values from 1 to 10). These 10 IDs are stored in our app as QB_Reference_IDs, so we can update a particular invoice by its QB ID. The question is - when we switch the account with 10 invoices to v3 **will the invoices change their IDs in QBO**, so we won't be able to access them by their previous IDs?

Comment: Yes, the IDs of the Invoices will be different in V3.

Comment: @PeterLavelle do you know some strategy to migrate those IDs? Or we have to export everything and then import with new IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Data will be intact. You can test it out from ApiExplorer.

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Thanks

Comment: Did you test that with old v2 account? Did you switched it to v3 and have the same IDs for all of the entities?

Comment: The data is the same.  It is only the calls and the format of the responses that change between V2 & V3.

V2 response
 <Id idDomain="QBO">7</Id>

V3 response
<Id>7</Id>